# PHP Login trough API (POST Request Error)

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

For our school project we need to create a graphical login interface with PHP.
We receive the login data from a selfwritten API and we have the following code which doesn't seem to work properly.
We can create a login and the login informations are stored in a database behind the API.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
//Definition der eingegebbenutzernameenen Daten im Formular
$benutzername = $_POST["benutzername"];
$passwort = $_POST["passwort"];

//Defintion der Verbindung
$url = 'http://IP:8080/login/Auth';

//Zusammenfügen der eingegebenen Daten und des XMLs
$xmlstring = "<request>
  <entity name=\"login\">
    <username>" . $benutzername . "</username>
    <password>" . $passwort . "</password>
    <apiUser>" . $benutzername . "</apiUser>
  </entity>
</request>
";

$curl = curl_init($url);

// Set the CURLOPT_POST option to true for POST request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Set the request data as JSON using json_encode function
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlstring);

// Set custom headers for RapidAPI Auth and Content-Type header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Content-Type: application/xml'
]);

// Execute cURL request with all previous settings
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// Close cURL session
curl_close($curl);
echo $response . PHP_EOL;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If we try to login we get the following error message:

> 1589983374885405Method Not Allowedorg.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedExceptionRequest method 'POST' not supported/login/Auth1

Comment: The api is clearly stating you can't use a POST to call the method login/Auth1
You should use a tool like Postman to simulate the request and once you have the response you need replicate the communication with php.

Comment: It seems like you're posting data to an endpoint that doesn't allow the POST method. We don't know how the API is built so there isn't really much we can do here